# How can I reduce the app.js size of my vuejs web app?

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

I am having app.js size of 1.76 MB and web app takes so much time to response.I'm using laravel in backend.

Answer (score 1):

Try minifying using uglify.js https://www.npmjs.com/package/uglify-js and make sure you have compression enabled